# How do I get a list of child elements using winappdriver in a win32 application?

Tags: c#, selenium, winapi, xpath, winappdriver

I am using WinAppDriver (using NUnit and C#) to test some legacy win32 Applications.

As I debug the tests, I reach certain points where I need to see a list of all child elements of the selected element.  This will allow me to build the next step in the test.

I have tried using different FindElementsXXX methods, but have not found any that work.  It seems that none have a wildcard search option.

Is there a syntax for XPath that will work in this situation?  I have seen several XPath snippets that "should" work, but I get errors that the pattern is not supported.

Comment: can you add one example that make clear what you want to achieve  ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an XPath expression for that.
Given `x` is a string for your XPath element, you need to append `/*` to it.
Example:
`/bookstore` is the element... `/bookstore/*` selects all its child elements. Reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: I'll give that a try when I get back to a Windows 10 box.  (Stuck on Windows 7 at work)

Comment: Do you have an example? By element, do you mean "bookstore" i the automation ID or something else? I am trying to use your advice for testing a wpf app so it's nt a web page although the elements are WebElement type in winappd speak.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid driver.  I had 8 patterns that wouldn't work.  The error was indicating that the pattern wasn't supported.

I ran across this post [Web Driver Issue 51](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/51) that indicated that some of the download links might be pointing to old versions.  Yep!  That was the problem.  The correct download link (as of Jan 30, 2017 is [v0.7-beta](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases/tag/v0.7-beta) )

Comment: I ended up doing my own XML parsing of the page source.  The only thing I cannot find is accessing sub-menus.  I can get the top level menu, but the sub-menu items are missing from the page source.

Answer (score 0):

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList">..</ListBox>
```

**WinAppDriver Test:**

```
var listBox = testSession.FindElementByAccessibilityId("MyList");
var comboBoxItems = listBox.FindElementsByClassName("ListBoxItem");
```

**XPath**:   [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp)  [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp)

```
var comboBoxItems = listBox.FindElementByXPath("//ListBoxItem"); // ok
```

In a real world scenario I would use something like this. But it is not working on my side too:

```
var xPath = "//ListBox[@Name=\"MyList\"]//ListBoxItem[@IsSelected=\"True\"]";
listBox.FindElementByXPath(xPath);        // => not working
listBox.FindElementByXPath("//ListBox");  // => empty?
listBox.FindElementByXPath("//ListView"); // => empty?
```

The child elements of a ComboBox are a bit special. They are created after clicking on the combo and I found some [open issues](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/issues/178) on that.

To debug I use Inspect.exe that is explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAJVpvaEchY) and Immediate window in VS. [The table](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver#supported-locators-to-find-ui-elements)  helps a bit to find out that:

- **WPF**     => **Inspect.exe**   => **WinAppDriver**
- x:Name  => AutomationId  => FindElementByAccessibilityId(*)
- Control type  => LocalizedControlType  => FindElementByClass(ToUpperCamelCase(*))